# tabBarController sending delegate methods to tabs that don't respond to them

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Using Storyboard I have setup an application with three tab bars. When I click on one of the tabs and have a singleton datasource class perform an action, and than immediately switch to another tab, when the singleton finishes fetching data externally it tries to send it to the current tab which causes a crash because the current tab I am on does not respond to the specific delegate method that I have implemented in the singleton delegate, and should not implement since there is no reason for that specific tab to perform that action. Here is how my delegate is currently setup.

```
@class DataHolder;

@protocol DataHolderControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)logout;
@optional
-(void)friendsQuarryDidFinishWithData;
-(void)pendingFriendsQuarryDidFinishWithData;
-(void)allUsersQuarryDidFinishWithData;
-(void)additionalFriendsFoundAndAdded;
-(void)messageQuarryFinishedWithData;
-(void)thumbnailQuaryDidFinishWithData;
-(void)sentRequestUsersFoundWithData; 
@end

@interface DataHolder : NSObject;
@property (nonatomic,weak) id <DataHolderControllerDelegate>delegate;
```

The delegate is called within the method when data is queried.

```
-(void)messageQuarry{
    PFQuery *messageQUery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
    messageQUery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    [messageQUery whereKey:@"recipientIds" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [messageQUery whereKey:@"file_type" equalTo:@"original_image.png"];
    [messageQUery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }else{
            messagesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:objects];
            [delegate messageQuarryFinishedWithData];
        }
    }];
}
```

Than, the view controller has a delegate method, this is the inboxViewController delegate method that is called when the delegate method above is called.

```
-(void)messageQuarryFinishedWithData{
    self.messages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:dataHolder.getMessages];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: You need to show the method that sends the data back to the tab. How is it determining where to send the data?

Comment: Edited the original question to include the information you requested.

Comment: I don't see why this should cause a crash. I assume only the tab that implements the delegate method is set as the delegate of the DataHolderControllerDelegate, it should be the only one that ever receives the delegate call. Are you getting any error message with the crash?

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ConnectionTableViewController messageQuarryFinishedWithData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance . messageQuarryFInishedWithData is an optional method that is not implemented by the connectionTableViewController. Starting from the homeTableViewControlelr, which does respond to the selector, and clicking on the connection tab for example causes a crash since the method isn't implemented. All viewControllers set the dataHolder delegate to self.

Comment: Only one object at a time can be the delegate of your protocol, so the fact that all your controllers are setting themselves as the delegate could be a problem. I think you need to rethink your strategy. I would probably use notifications rather than delegation if the DataHolder class needs to be sending information to all your controllers.

Comment: NSarray and NSmutableArray are not KVO compliant, which Notification classes/methods would you recommend?

Comment: I'm not sure what KVO has to do with anything. Your DataHolder class can send any notifications you want, and all your controllers can register for which ever ones they are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Delegates are meant to be intimate, meaning that its a 1-1 type relationship. It seems that what you are looking for is having a one-to-many relationship which is what NSNotificationCenter is used for. I recommend looking up the NSNotificationCenter documentation form Apple.